# How to use value in view bag as attribute of <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to assign value from viewbag as one of the attribute of javascript  tag in cshmt file. Im using asp .net mvc3. Im having value inside viewbag["myvalue"] . I need to use this value like

```
<script src="https://abcb.js?session_ id=1234&mytext="+'viewbag["myvalue"]' type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Is it possible to do this? Please provide the code if it is possible

**Edited** : Im using razor view engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this?

Sure.

> Please provide the code if it is possible

Sure, for Razor:

```
<script src="https://abcb.js?session_id=1234&mytext=@ViewVag.myvalue" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and if you are using the WebForms view engine:

```
<script src="https://abcb.js?session_id=1234&mytext=<%= ViewVag.myvalue %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Darin. Its not working. Value inside viewbag is not getting passed. Insted, its being passed a string "@ViewVag.myvalue".

Comment: Are you using the Razor view engine? I've updated my post to shown an example with the WebForms view engine if that is what you are using.

Comment: Its working now.I missed on tag which was why i couldnt get it right. Thanks Darin for the quick and correct response